# Mountains had metal ores inside them in Medieval Times, or were they planted in there only after the Space Age?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Coming from Minecraft to Medieval Engineers, I thought that I would find most metal ores inside rocks in the mountains. But mining, so far, gave me inventories full of rocks, and the view of more rocks to be mined, only.

Mining through mountains is useful?

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking in the wrong place.

You can find ores by looking at places which have odd-colored grass.

Comment: The question was: "Mining through mountains is useful?". Could you please tell something about mountains on your answer?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah based on this answer: no. Mining through mountains is not useful; try mining under odd-colored grass if you are looking for ores.